# Html and CSS second level drop down

Tags: html, css, menu

So I've had a rough look around a few questions but attempted to use the same ideas and couldn't get this to work? Was hoping one of you might be able to assist me here?

I am basically trying to create a second level drop down menu using a provided template which doesn't have it built in, when I used the code below, the menu shows and then you have bullet pointed links below which looks hilarious. I am trying to get it to style right with the template but am unsure on how to achieve this? Here are the codes I have already attempted.

HTML NORMAL CODE

```
<body class="homepage">
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> SnappySites</a></a> </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container--> 
  </nav>
  <!--/nav--> 

</header>
<!--/header-->
```

HTML CODE I AM LOOKING TO ACHIEVE

```
<body class="homepage">
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> SnappySites</a></a> </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a>Second level link 1</a></li>
              <li><a>Second level link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container--> 
  </nav>
  <!--/nav--> 

</header>
<!--/header-->
```

CSS CODE

```
/*************************
*******Header******
**************************/

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #151515;
    padding: 15px 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    border: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand .fa {
    color: #3498db;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I know it would need to have such codes in the CSS script as...

```
.navbar-nav>ul {
        margin-left: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 28px;
    }
```

But not too sure? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the parent `<li>` CSS position property to ‘relative’.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

li ul { display: none; }

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
```

And go from there? This is only sample code I have come across and more information can be found [here](http://www.cssscript.com/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/) but it should help you to get started on building it in to your current project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Saying your nav is a fixed width you can use the code below and/or the attached [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt5876ao/1/) I created using the code you provided. I hope it helps!

Here is the HTML bit

```
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> SnappySites</a></a> </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-us.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a>Second level link 1</a></li>
              <li><a>Second level link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container--> 
  </nav>
  <!--/nav--> 
</header>
```

and the CSS

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;

    list-style: none;  /*Added*/
    display: inline;   /*Added*/
}

.navbar-nav li ul      /*Added*/
{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none:  /* removes the bullets */
}

.navbar-nav li:hover ul  /*Added*/
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px

}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    border: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand .fa {
    color: #3498db;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added the code in and it is still showing as just "red" bullet point links across the other side of the website. Any idea why this would be happening? Thanks

Comment: Is the red bullet on the first or second level? I updated the fiddle and the code to remove the 2nd level header bullets.

Comment: The bullet points are on the second level so technically it is working, although the style isn't showing and its just appearing as red text with bullet points on the far right of the website (under the pricing link). I can't even see the second level link 2 as it's hidden away under the BODY section. Can literally only see the word "second" but there is no box around it or anything, just text.

Comment: I've updating the code using your updates and still having the same result. Thank you for your help with this though.